# VB.Net About dividing Currency by an X amount of months

Tags: vb.net, currency

im trying to learn how to made stuff with currency.

For example:
I divide 10.000$ by 12 Months, rounding with 2 decimals i have 833,33 $.

If i multiply 833,33 $ * 12 i got 9999,96 $, so there is 0.04 of possible loss.
Rounding the 9999.96 with 2 decimals of presition i got 10.000 $ but that's what i don't want since 0.04 is a loss.

Im using SQL Compact 4.0 as database, the price_month table is decimal(18,2)

Here is my code:

```
    Dim price as Decimal = 10000
    Dim pricemonth as Decimal = Math.round((price/12),2) ' 833.33
    Console.Writeline(pricemonth*12) ' 9999.96
    Console.Writeline(Math.round((pricemonth*12),2)) ' 10000
```

Any advice how to increase accuracy with currency? Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't round your calculation. Leave the original numbers untouched but when you display the answer round it so that it looks nice.